# crontab won't work on mac 10.6.7

Tags: macos, cron

i create a simple cron job by editing /etc/crontab as following:

```
*/2     *       *       *       *       *       php /Users/min/Documents/testcron.php
```

and the testcron.php  is simple as:

```
<?php

$fd = fopen("/Users/min/Documents/testcron.txt", 'a');
fwrite($fd, "test--cron--\n");
fclose($fd);
?>
```

then simply save the crontab file and hope magic happen, but nothing happened. i even run the command manually and it worked.

```
php /Users/min/Documents/testcron.php
```

anyone have any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not certain, but I bet your file is not being read. Perhaps you have to do

```
$ crontab -e
```

to edit, and then it gets read properly after you save?

You could probably test this theory by doing

```
$ crontab -l
```

to list the table to see if it is working already.

Comment: ok, i ran crontab -e to rewrote the file, though i m sick of vi, then ran crontab -l, now it complained:crontab: no crontab for min, does it matter where i ran the crontab -e?

Comment: @ohana: It does not matter from where you run `crontab -e`. But you have to be logged in as the user with whose rights the cronjob shall run. Did `crontab -e` give an output like "Installing new crontab for min" when you saved the crontab and closed vi? Btw.: You can avoid to use vi by setting the `EDITOR` environment variable to something else.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick note, on some systems you have to do sudo crontab -e  , and sudo crontab -l because otherwise you won't have the proper permissions to create or view crontabs

Answer (score 0):

I think there's one column too much. You have 6 time specification columns - it should be 5: minute, hour, day of month, month, day of week:

```
*/2 * * * * php /Users/min/Documents/testcron.php
```

Comment: that are 5 columns: */2 means every 2 min.

Comment: i mistyped here with one more column, but in my file it is 5 columns.

Comment: @ohana: So it seems to be a different problem. Do you see anything in e.g. `/var/log/messages`?